# Run Java Code after a Method Return?

Tags: java, service, methods, web, return

I have a web service that is based on Java classes. Is it possible to run code after an acknowledge message has been returned within Java method of the called operation.

To understand better, this is the workflow:

1. Call a specific operation (method) of my web service
2. Start processing
3. Sent an ack that the processing has been started (this is done be a return value)
4. Continue processing

Threads do not work, since the threads need to be terminated before the return of the method.

Does anybody has an idea how to implement this scenario or an alternative to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to return from a method but not return from the method? That will be problematic.

Comment: Huh? Why do Threads do not work? This sounds like a very invalid statement

Comment: Why do you say that Thread needs to be terminated before the return ?

Comment: Thanks for the rapid responses. Threads really work in this case. I still had in mind a certain thread-process dependency. But the thread survives the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use Threads for this, as you are splitting program flow into two; the returning path and the processing path are separating and running alongside each other.

If you need the acknowledgement for the method start to be sent by the return of the method then why can't your service providing methods look as simple as something like this?

```
public Acknowledgement someService() {
  new Thread(new SomeServiceRunnable()).start();
  return new Acknowledgement();
}
```

The service will be started, then the method will return (thus notifying that the process has started) whilst the processing continues until the thread ends...

Am I missing something here about what you need to achieve?

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

It seems that some answers have been engineered to address problems which I did not see as being presented as part of the question. Here are some assumptions I made when making my answer, presented so that anyone reading this answer might have a better idea of when it might not apply to their particular situation:

This is for a situation where you want only to acknowledge that a service has conceptually speaking begun execution. The acknowledgement can give no information about the success of any part of this execution or its initialisation, only that it has conceptually started, that is to say that the Associated Runnables run() will be called at some point.

Of course if you want the execution to start and the caller to return, then the significance of the acknowledgement will necessarily be limited by just exactly how much of the task waited to be executed before returning, here no waiting is done and the acknowledgement is returned immediately, and so no extra information can be given.

Comment: This is the correct answer? Really? IMHO this is totally useless as you're not acknowledging anything. How do you know if Thread has successfully started processing, or started **at all**? This works only if you don't want to signal **inside** the Thread code, which is how you should do it IMHO. With this you would return an acknowledgment without really acknowledging anything... which is the same as spawning the Thread and continue without caring about if the Thread has successfully started processing.

Comment: As I said, this answer was given on the condition that thomelicious needed the acknowledgement to be sent by the return of the method; he specifically said: '[the service should] run code after an ackknowledge message has been returned'.

As for giving confirmation that it has started, why should I have any reason not to trust that Thread.start() will work? If it was not to be trusted it would throw a checked exception IMHO, and if some unusual problem does occur, an unchecked one surely would be thrown. How failures are dealt with after the thread starts is up to thomelicious.

Comment: Well, if '[the service should] **run code** after an acknowledge message has been returned', your answer does not guarantee the service will be running the code. What if the Thread fails to start (looking only at the most obvious mistake here)? You returned an ack wrongly. He also said: "Sent an ack that **the processing has been started**". Pretty much clear to me. Your answer is just plain wrong. I hope he'll figure this when that code starts to fail...

Comment: How could processing could fail to start here? Under what conditions do you imagine Thread.start() would silently fail? If such conditions exist then please enlighten me to them.

AFAIU Thread.start() is a guarantee that run() will be called for that Thread. I have no reason to assume that thomelicious has no provisions in place to deal with failures which happen in that Thread, once started.

The way the question was described, the 'acknowledgement' only needed to be a fairly empty guarantee that execution has begun. The only thing I failed to answer was your *interpretation* of the question.

Comment: P.S. Please try not to be so rude in the way in which you conduct yourself, this should be a friendly and constructive community, yes?

I will edit my answer to clarify regarding what I feel to be your misinterpretation of the question.

Thank you :).

Comment: I'm not being rude, I'm just stating your answer **IMHO** is just **plain wrong**. If that is rude for you... well I'm so sorry if you don't accept constructive criticism. Anyways, I didn't interpret anything. I quoted what he said: "Sent an ack that **the processing has been started**". You're not sending an ack **after** the processing has been started, but **before** it has been started, which is just **useless**. You're not doing anything in someService() method. You can just do *new Thread(new SomeServiceRunnable()).start();*. That would have the same result as your code.

Comment: Conceptually, and functionally, since no data about how the execution has been started needs to be returned, how is this distinction important? What *use* do you actually gain by waiting until the start of the Thread has been executed as opposed to just acknowledging that it has been queued for execution?

And yes, that would have the same result, I was working within the specifications of the question and as such assumed that there was a reason the asker wanted his services exposed as methods.

The rudeness I referred to was in the confrontational phrasing of your response.

Comment: *"What use do you actually gain by waiting until the start of the Thread has been executed as opposed to just acknowledging that it has been queued for execution?"* Because you don't know what code the Thread will be excuting. My answer is safer in more cases than yours. Anyway, I'm out of this discussion. Have fun :)

Comment: Exactly, I don't know, you don't know. The added safety of your method *could* be useful, but only given certain assumptions you made.
Presumably the service will *already* need to communicate with the caller after beginning execution as it is. By leaving more detailed confirmation until later, I am just assuming it will be communicated through the same medium as any other information the service sends back to the client. The more you defer acknowledgement to collect data about successful service initialisation, the closer you get to just waiting until it's done and returning its success...

Comment: I would return the ack **just before** the processing starts. If the processing starts right at the beginning of *run()*, then yes, your answer is correct. In all other cases, it is not. My answer is valid in all cases. But I also understand the OP wanted code ;)

Comment: IMHO, the solution of Elias is reasonable. It fulfils what I need: The acknowledgement of invocation of an operation (method) of my service. It makes sure that the method that is called by a specific operation exists and could be invoked. I am sorry for the ambiguous question esp. in Step 3 of the workflow. Literally, m0skit0 is correct: Make sure that the thread itself is started. IMHO, this depends on the requirements of what needs to be acknowledged: either only the service invocation or the processing itself (or better the initialization of the processing, afterwards the ack)....

Comment: ….I have certain exception handlings related to the processing within the Thread. In addition, depending on the level, it would make sense to acknowledge directly via a callback method to the client without expecting a return value within the service request (as suggested by Sajan).

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

How about invoking a callback method to the client.
See the workflow

1. Call a specific operation (method) of my web service
2. Start processing
3. Call a method on the client, sending an acknowledgement.
4. Continue processing

Answer (score 1):

> Threads do not works, since the threads need to be terminated before
>   the return of the method.

Wrong. Threads share variables, and thus can share data between threads with no need to return from the thread. Taking your example:

> Call a specific operation (method) of my web service

Spawn new thread for this

> Sent an ack that the processing has been started (this is done be a return value)

No, don't do it by return value. The new thread sends a message to whatever class you want (calls a method, changes a variable...). With this you can signal anything you want to any thread you want. Just beware of racing conditions, and use "synchronized" keyword when needed!

> Continue processing

The new thread continues to process, as does the main one.

Comment: Any comments on why downvoted or is this plain childish vengeance? ;)

Comment: I have explained my position in the comments and edit to my own answer, and was entering them there first in the hopes that my answer would guarded against what I feel to be a misinterpretation.

Comment: To reiterate here, with more of a focus on how it applies to your answer: I feel that this is an over-complication, and adds unnecessary waiting. The asker only wanted confirmation that the service was started, which conceptually (in every sense which I think is important here) is given by calling `Thread.start()`.

If the acknowledgement needed to contain information about the success of some initial part of the execution of the service, then of course it would need to wait and it would be best as you say to send this confirmation message from the service Thread, but this wasn't the question.

Comment: I'll quote the question again, maybe you didn't read me/him: "Sent an ack that **the processing has been started**". I don't see where my answer is wrong, but I do see where yours is: you're returning an ack about the Thread being started, not the processing. And your answer is also an overcomplication because you don't even need that someService() method, and you don't need to return a new Acknowledgement object. Useless use of memory. Code bloat. It simply does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is creating a thread:

```
public boolean beginWorkAndSendAck(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){ 
        public void run(){
            //Do something here
        }
    }
    t.start();
    return true;
}
```

The thread will carry on after the 'main' thread dies away. The problem you may be referring to, is if the web-service shuts down the process after the ack is sent. The thread *should* keep going, as java doesn't shut down its process unless all threads are done.

If it isn't working, it might the web service is doing some voodoo - closing the java process or somesuch. I'd suggest looking into creating a new process with java, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html which would require a separate application to perform the job you need.

Comment: Same mistake as Elias Vasylenko's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
              //task to complete after sending acknowledge   
    }
};
t.start();
//prepare acknowledgement code and return;
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

task inside run() method will keep on running even after return.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for an asynchronous Web service invocation:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html